# Linq update query on single row?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I'm trying to do a simple `UPDATE` on a column of a single row. I'm getting a `Sequence contains no elements` exception.

```
private void InsertUpdateFileLocation(string targetFileLocationAndFullName, 
    tbFileAttachment linkGuid)
{
    ISESEntities context = new ISESEntities();

    var query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
                 where f.CCCPGUID == linkGuid.CCCPGUID
                 select f).First();

    query.FileLocation = targetFileLocationAndFullName;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You don't have a record matching this condition `f.CCCPGUID == linkGuid.CCCPGUID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have no records matching that value you are searching for. You can catch this by using `FirstOrDefault` then testing for null:

```
var query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
             where f.CCCPGUID == linkGuid.CCCPGUID
             select f).FirstOrDefault();

if(query==null) 
{
    //no match found!
}
```